# Regex to get groups delimited by tags

Tags: regex

I have this sample string:

```
blablablablaGROUP1blablablablaGROUP2blablablablaGROUP3blablablabla
```

The pattern which Split the groups is `GROUP\d` as you can see.

I would like to get this result in groups like this:

> 1. `GROUP1blablablabla`
> 2. `GROUP2blablablabla`
> 3. `GROUP3blablablabla`

The number of groups could be from 0 to n.

I have tried with this one, but no luck for the moment:

```
(GROUP\d.*(?=GROUP\d))
```

I am working with .NET.

Comment: "groups" is a bit confusing since there are matching groups. I think the term `matches` is best suited here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will give you 3 groups:

```
(GROUP\d.*?(?=GROUP\d|$))
```

Comment: Don't forget [to explain the pattern](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177757/are-answers-that-just-contain-a-regular-expression-pattern-really-good-answers)

Answer (score 1):

You need something like..

```
(GROUP\d.*)+$
```

..

```
(                        group and capture to \1 (1 or more times)
 GROUP                   match 'GROUP'
    \d                   match a digit (0-9)
     .*                  any character except newline (0 or more times)
)+                       end of \1 +(match 1 or more times)
$                        end of string
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use

```
(GROUP((?!GROUP).)+)
```

Meaning

```
(       start of  capturing group
GROUP   Match the string literal GROUP
(
  (?!GROUP) Negative lookahead to makesure the text after the current match charater is not GROUP
.)+     Repeat the same 1 or more times
```

You can then access these groups as 1, 2, 3 (3 matches as per your input)